# My Android service launched from React Native should open a socket.io connection to localhost but isn't connecting, why?

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io

I have a React-Native app, and I expose a method to JS that starts a service in Android. I want the service to open a socket.io connection to localhost. I'm trying to do this in its `onCreate` method. The service is started, but the socket is not connecting and I can not figure out why. I am doing this on an emulator in Android Studio.

Here is the Android code:

MyModule.java

```
package com.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static final String TAG = "MyModule";

    public MyModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    // Service-related
    private MyModuleService myService;
    private boolean bound = false;
    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder binder) {
            MyModuleService.MyModuleBinder myModuleBinder =
                    (MyModuleService.MyModuleBinder) binder;
            myService = myModuleBinder.getService();
            bound = true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };
    // \Service-related

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startService() {
        Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyModuleService.class);
        activity.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

MyService.js

```
package com.myproject;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.util.Log;


import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Random;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


public class MyModuleService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyModuleService";
    private final IBinder binder = new MyModuleBinder();
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public class MyModuleBinder extends Binder {
        MyModuleService getService() {
            return MyModuleService.this;
        }
    }

    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String url = "https://localhost:5000";
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(url);
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "call: CONNECTED");  // this never runs
                }

            });
            socket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("URI " + url + " is a malformed URL");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried local ip instead of localhost for url string?

Comment: I have yes. Does not work

Comment: Apparently this has to do with security in Android. I can't yet explain why a websocket connection initiated over HTTP doesn't go through, I can say that using HTTPS and setting some network security settings in AndroidManifest and adding a certificate to my resources matching the one on the server makes the connection work.